# What to do on navratri?

Tags: mantras, durga, kali, saraswati, navrathri

What are the best thing to do on navratri,
Any type of yoga,or mantra(pls don't suggest any which need initiation) or anything else

Comment: Deleted my first comment cause it was far too long but real quick some options : 1. Basic beginner NavDurga puja for each of the nine days 2. Partial fasts, till sundown, nothing too difficult, phal-ahar type thing 3. Start to look up how to listen/shravan of Durga Saptashati and the accompanying things to be read, etc. Thx for making this post ! :) Good stuff ! Countdown is on comrade, Navratri starts Monday 9/26 :D